# How can I put int or size_t variables into a char array?

Tags: c

Hello everyone so i want to put a size_t variable of a number up to 4096 in order to keep track of how much "memory" i used in the array (yes it has to be a char array). So for example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void)
{
char mem[4096] = {0};
size_t size = 4095;
mem[0] = size;
//then somehow be able to size = mem[0] to be able to recall the size later. 
    return 0;
}
```

I just want to be able to put a number in the first array elment in order to be able to keep track of how many elements ive used.
Im implementating a heap memory and i also have to implement malloc(), and free() i have a char array that simulates the heap memory, and i cant use global/ static local variables but i want to be able to keep track of the heap size. My best thought of action was to store the heap size in the "Heap" (char array) to be able to keep track of it.

Comment: Not possible with `char` which is only one byte. Even making it unsigned can only store a max value of 255.

Comment: A char can only hold 8 bits.  How would you like to represent 4095 using only 8 bits?  If you know that the total number of different values you will store is fewer than 256, you could do this (with a look up table).  Otherwise, there's no way to store the information without loss.

Comment: XY problem. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: It sounds like you actually want to declare a struct in which one of the members is a `size_t`.

Comment: @CostantinoGrana Im implementating a heap memory and i also have to implement malloc(), and free() i have a char array that simulates the heap memory, and i cant use global/ static local variables but i want to be able to keep track of the heap size. My best thought of action was to store the heap size in the "Heap" (char array) to be able to keep track of it.

Comment: If I guess correctly, you are trying to write some sort of "header" of a 4096 bytes wide memory area. What you are trying to do makes no sense, but there are several other ways to do that. You could for example define a packed structure `{size_t size; char data[N];}`

Comment: If you really, really want to store the size in the array, and if it really, really has to be an array of `char`, and if the size might be greater than 255 (but less than 65536), then you can theoretically do this by storing the size in the first *two* elements of the array, `mem[0]` and `mem[1]`.

Comment: @SteveSummit yes i was thinking about doing that but then how would i recall it

Comment: By using `memcpy ()` for both storing and retrieving the value. But anyway you'll have to pay attention when you write data.

Answer (score 1):

If you *must* use a char array for storing the number of bytes used, you have (at least) two choices:

1. create a union of an uint16_t with the array. This will allow you to use the first two bytes to hold the number of bytes used.
2. essentially the same as #1 but do the math manually, and maintain the bytes yourself.

I'd recommend #1.

Comment: for #2 you can use `memcpy` instead of doing math

Comment: By "doing the math" I meant performing the mod256 and /256 stuff. Really not the recommended approach unless someone just hates unions.

Answer (score 1):

About the most straightforward way to do this that is defined by the C standard is with to copy the bytes from the size object to the memory:

```
memcpy(&mem[index], &size, sizeof size);
```

Good compilers with optimization enabled will optimize this to a store from `size` to memory if they can determine `&mem[index]` is suitably aligned (or an unaligned store instruction is available and a good method). The reverse, to retrieve the size, is `memcpy(&size, &mem[index], sizeof size);`.

It can be done with unions, but that may be cumbersome in this situation. The union would have to include the entire array.

Old C code would simply cast an address in `mem` to the desired type, as with `* (size_t *) &mem[index] = size;`. However, the C standard does not define the behavior when an array defined as an array of `char` is accessed through a `size_t` lvalue as the above does. This worked with old compilers, and modern compilers may still support it if an appropriate switch is given to ask the compiler to support it, but it is needless, so new code should avoid this in favor of more portability.

Note that you do not need to use a `size_t` if the size will only be 4096. For this, you can use `uint16_t`.

Another option is to calculate the two bytes:

```
static void RecordSize(unsigned char *memory, uint16_t size)
{
    memory[0] = size >> 8; // Record high bits.
    memory[1] = size;      // Record low bits.
        // This will automatically “chop off” high bits.
}

static uint16_t RetrieveSize(unsigned char *memory)
{
    return (uint16_t) memory[0] << 8 | memory[1];
}

…

RecordSize(&mem[index], size);
…
size = RetrieveSize(&mem[index];
```

That would be used more rarely than the direct copy, but it could be useful if data is being recorded in memory to transmit to another computer system that may use a different byte ordering for its integers. This method explicitly stores the high bits first and the low bits second (or the code could be written to do the opposite, as desired).

Note that this code uses `unsigned char`. You should generally prefer to use `unsigned char` for manipulations of bytes as arbitrary data, as it avoids some problems that can occur with signed types. (The C standard leaves it implementation-defined whether the `char` type is signed or unsigned.)

Comment: This is very nice. As usual I came up with a macro like `#define VEC_SIZE(v) ((uint16_t*)(v))[2046]`, but it's UB. Sigh...

Comment: I'd put the size at the end of the array, just to have 0 based addressing in the memory chunk.